# How to change label text of custom UINavigationBar class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a custom navigation bar class. Here is my code. The question is how can I set the label text (`navTitle` and `teamName`) with my own method from other class. Like this method `[self.navigationbar setTitle:@""]`.

```
#import "CustomNavigationBar.h"

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage *navImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav"];
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, r, navImage.CGImage);

    UIImageView *teamId = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(210, 17, 40, 10)];
    teamId.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"team"];

    UILabel *navTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 2, 200, 39)];
    navTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    navTitle.text = @"title";
    navTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    navTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];

    UILabel *teamName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(255, 18, 78, 10)];
    teamName.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    teamName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    teamName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    teamName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10];

    [self addSubview:teamId];
    [self addSubview:navTitle];
    [self addSubview:teamName];
}

@end
```

Comment: What the hell are you doing in your `drawRect:`? :O this is a huge misuse :O It is for *drawing only* and not for instantiating kinda everything or even call `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add a global variable navTitle like this:

```
@implementation CustomNavigationBar
static UILabel *navTitle;
```

Then in your `drawRect` method simply instantiate it:

```
navTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 2, 200, 39)];
```

Then add this method in your `CustomNavigationBar.h`:

```
+(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

Then add this in your `CustomNavigationBar.m`:

```
+(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
    [navTitle setText:title];
}
```

Then in your other class simply import the CustomNavigationBar.h and call the method:

```
[CustomNavigationBar setTitle:@"myTitle"];
```

Comment: I got the error, No known class method for selector "viewWithTag". By the way, CustomNavigationBar class is a subclass of UINavigation Bar. I already tried code like but the label text don`t change.